# XSLT - changes number exist within text() node

Tags: regex, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm doing xml to xml transformation using XSLT and I have a XML code like follows.

```
<section>
   <para>height 10cm, width 15cm</para>
   <para>height 20cm, width 15cm</para>
   <para>height 10cm, width 22cm</para>
</section>
```

here I need to double the height and width value in the output. So transformed xml would be,

```
<section>
   <para>height 20cm, width 30cm</para>
   <para>height 40cm, width 30cm</para>
   <para>height 20cm, width 44cm</para>
</section>
```

I thought about use XSLT regex to solve this matter and wrote following template,

```
<xsl:template match="para/text()">
        <xsl:variable name="elValue" select="."/>

        <xsl:analyze-string select="$elValue" regex="(\d{{5}}(\-\d{{4}})?)\s*">

            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="number(regex-group(1))*2"/>
            </xsl:matching-substring>

            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>

        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>
```

but it does not work as expected.

can anyone suggest me a method how can I doubled that numbers exist within para elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am far from being a regex whiz, but this seems to be working for me:

```
<xsl:template match="para/text()">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\d+">

    <xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="2 * number(.)"/>
    </xsl:matching-substring>

    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>

    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: ,This works fine. thanks, :)  further more what if I need to doubled up only single digit numbers here. I tried with 'regex="\d"' but it convert more that single digit numbers as well. (exmple - 'height 155' convert to 'height 21010'). how can I restrict this regex to doubled up only single digit numbers?

Comment: @sanjay I suggest you post another question with a suitable example.

Comment: michael.hor257k, I've put a the question with a scenario http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34807010/xslt-regex-select-only-one-digit-number-from-text-node