# XSLT - get number value of the text() node

Tags: regex, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have XML file like follows,

```
<sec>
    <para>Section 1- TOC</para>
    <para>Section 4* Main</para>
    <para>Section 3$ Basic content</para>
    <para>Section 11_ Section 10</para>
    <para>Section 15@ Appendix 6</para>
</sec>
```

I need to get the number followed by 'Section' string in the `text()` node using function.

example:

```
<xsl:function name="abc:get-section-number">
        <xsl:param name="string" as="xs:string"/>

        <xsl:sequence select="tokenize($string,'\d+')[1]"/>
    </xsl:function>
```

this example returns the substring before the number value but I need to get the number value after 'Section' string.. (output values should be 1,4,3,11 and 15)

I tried with some in-build functions (string-before, strong-after, matches..) but couldn't find any proper solution.

can anyone suggest me a method to get this number value?

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34807281/3832970). You seem to need just `Section\s+(\d+)`. Then `<xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `analyze-string`, as already suggested in a comment, see http://xsltransform.net/3NJ38Zy for a working sample which does

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:abc="http://example.com/abc"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs abc">

    <xsl:function name="abc:get-section-number" as="xs:integer">
        <xsl:param name="string" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:analyze-string select="$string" regex="^Section\s+([0-9]+)">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:sequence select="xs:integer(regex-group(1))"/>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="para">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="abc:get-section-number(.)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```